# Make a webpage where it looks like the browser is hanging / crashing

Tags: popularity-contest, browser

Your task today is to create a HTML page.

This page, when opened in a browser, behaves as if the browser has a problem (hanging, crashing, network error, virus, etc.)

- You **can** use all the HTML(5), CSS(3) and JavaScript features you want.
- You **can't** use Flash or other plugins.
- You **can't** provoke a real problem in the browser (for example, you can't make the browser hang with an infinite loop, or crash with a bug exploit, etc.), just make it *look like* there is a problem.

Please post your source code and provide an URL to view your page, and precise on which browsers / devices it works (if specific).

I recommend http://www.c99.nl/ to host your page easily.

This is a popularity contest, so the most upvoted answer wins!

Thanks, and have fun!

Comment: I think this could have some interesting results, even though it's a very broad challenge.

Comment: I do not see what is unclear at the moment, I voted for reopening. It is of course a broad challenge as @nderscore mentioned, all in all a rather creative task than a programming challenge and I think that this has to have its place here too.

Comment: it seems to me challenges like this are the exact reason the admins were so hesitant to allow [tag:popularity-contest] on the site.. no real objective way to identify a "correct answer"

Comment: @ardnew thats why its a [tag:popularity-contest], there is no right or wrong. the one with the most votes wins.

Comment: @TeunPronk No - *A popularity-contest is a competition where the correct answer with the highest vote tally (upvotes minus downvotes) wins, usually the most creative answer.* Each [tag:popularity-contest] must give precise requirements such that we can judge if an answer is *correct*.

Comment: @Howard okay, fair enough.. my bad. On the other hand, he did give requirements even if there aren't a lot but they are there.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more fun to see who could actually crash the browser fastest with the smallest amount of code ?

Answer (score 6):

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Connecting...</title>
 </head>

 <body style="margin: 0px; overflow:hidden;">
  <div style="position: relative;">
   <div style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; cursor:wait;"></div>
   <iframe src="http://www.wikipedia.com/" width="100%" height="100%" style="border: 0px;">
   </iframe>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

http://c99.nl/f/64943.html

Comment: neat! you could get rid of double scrollbars with overflow:hidden on the body or something like that. And use an iframe instead of object (for semanticity)

Comment: That doesn't hang for me.

Comment: `cursor: wait` is the trick.

Comment: @xem thanks, I changed it as you suggested!

Comment: @vauge Works now.

Answer (score 4):

### Better don't mess with Bond villains

[Enter Blofelds secret ambush...](http://c99.nl/f/64447.html)

And in case you want to see the code:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Gd4T/1/)

> After 3 seconds there will pop up a message, that the script isn't responding, but that's only an alert popup and not a real message from a hanging page. After 15 seconds there will be additional greetings from Blofeld.

Comment: I like it, but I get a notification of an unresponsive script which is something that shouldn't happen I believe. even though you seem to generate that yourself.

Comment: @TeunPronk No, that's supposed to happen.

Comment: @TeunPronk I got you! That's exactly what should happen, but it's not a real warning only an alert.

Comment: I haven't used javascript in forever, but can't you use something like `window.location` appended with some javascript filename to make the domain appear to match?

Answer (score 4):

## Zombie Error

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/141246873/ZombieError/index.html

Note: It might take a few seconds to load due to the image file.

The webpage consists of the below html, css and javascript as well as an image file zombie.png (graphics by Clint Bellanger [licensed CC-BY 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/)).

Tested in google chrome v36, but I expect it will work in most browsers.

#### Update:

26th Jul: Now removes zombies once they walk off the screen

28th Jul: You can now click on the zombies to blast them off the website

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Zombie Error</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" type="text/css" />
    <script src="zombie.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0px;">
    <div style="position: relative;">
        <div style="margin: 0 auto; width:100%; height:100%;">
            <iframe src="https://godaddy.com/" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; border-width: 0px;"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
}

span {
    font-style: italic;
}

.zombie{
    width: 78px;
    height: 78px;
    background-image: url('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/141246873/ZombieError/zombie.png');
    background-position: left;
    background-position-x: 0px;
    background-position-y: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 10px;
}

body{
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Javascript:

```
var directionWest = 0;
var directionNorth = 6;
var directionEast = 4;
var directionSouth = 2;

var stateWalking = 0;
var stateDying = 1;
var stateDead = 2;

var animWalk = {
    speed: 0.15,
    numFrames: 8,
    frames: [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
}

var animDying = {
    speed: 0.10,
    numFrames: 8,
    frames: [28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35]
}

var spriteWidth = 128;
var spriteHeight = 128;

var spriteOffsetX = 25;
var spriteOffsetY = 25;

var spritesheetWidth = 4608;

function Zombie(_id, _x, _y, _direction) {
    this.direction = _direction
    this.id = _id;
    this.pos = { x: _x, y: _y }
    this.anim = animWalk;
    this.animFrame = 0;
    this.animDelta = 0;
    this.speed = 30;
    this.state = stateWalking;
    this.corpseDelta = 0;
    return this;
}

Zombie.prototype.Update = function (delta) {
    if (this.state == stateDead)
        return;

    //update the animation frame
    this.animDelta += delta;
    if (this.animDelta >= this.anim.speed) {
        this.animDelta -= this.anim.speed;
        this.animFrame++;
        if (this.animFrame >= this.anim.numFrames)
            this.animFrame = 0;
    }

    //background-position-x
    var div = document.getElementById(this.id);
    div.style.backgroundPositionX = ((spritesheetWidth - (spriteWidth * this.anim.frames[this.animFrame])) - spriteOffsetX) + "px";
    div.style.backgroundPositionY = ((spriteHeight * this.direction) - spriteOffsetY) + "px";

    if (this.state == stateWalking) {
        //update position
        if (this.direction == directionEast)
            this.pos.x += (this.speed * delta);
        if (this.direction == directionWest)
            this.pos.x -= (this.speed * delta);
        if (this.direction == directionNorth)
            this.pos.y -= (this.speed * delta);
        if (this.direction == directionSouth)
            this.pos.y += (this.speed * delta);
        div.style.left = Math.floor(this.pos.x) + "px";
        div.style.top = Math.floor(this.pos.y) + "px";
    }
    else if (this.state == stateDying && this.animFrame == (this.anim.numFrames - 1)) {
        this.state = stateDead;
    }
}

var zombies = []

var nextZombieID = 0;

function GetZombie(zombieID)
{
    return zombies.filter(function (z) { return z.id == zombieID })[0];
}

function ZombieClick(div)
{
    var zombie = GetZombie(div.srcElement.id);

    if (zombie.state == stateWalking) {
        zombie.state = stateDying;
        zombie.animFrame = 0;
        zombie.animDelta = 0;
        zombie.anim = animDying;
    }
}

function NewZombie()
{
    var x = 0;
    var y = 0;
    var direction = 0;

    var rand = Math.random();
    if (rand < 0.25)
    {
        //spawn from left of screen
        x = spriteWidth * -1;
        y = (Math.random() * screen.height) - spriteHeight;
        direction = directionEast;
    }
    else if (rand < 0.5) {
        //spawn from right of screen
        x = screen.width;
        y = (Math.random() * screen.height) - spriteHeight;
        direction = directionWest;
    }
    else if (rand < 0.75) {
        //spawn from top of screen
        x = (Math.random() * screen.width) - spriteWidth;
        y = spriteWidth * -1;
        direction = directionSouth;
    }
    else {
        //spawn from bottom
        x = (Math.random() * screen.width) - spriteWidth;
        y = screen.height;
        direction = directionNorth;
    }

    //generate an id
    var id = nextZombieID;
    nextZombieID++;

    //create a div
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.id = id;
    div.classList.add("zombie");
    div.onclick = ZombieClick;
    document.body.appendChild(div);

    //create a zombie
    zombies.push(new Zombie(id, x, y, direction));
}

var spawnRate = 1;
var spawnDelta = 0;

function spawnZombies(delta)
{
    spawnDelta += delta;
    if (spawnDelta >= spawnRate) {
        spawnDelta -= spawnRate;
        NewZombie();
    }
}

var corpseDuration = 3;

function cleanupZombies(delta)
{
    for (var i = zombies.length - 1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
        //if the zombie has walked off the screen, remove them
        if (zombies[i].pos.x < (spriteWidth * -2)
            || zombies[i].pos.x > screen.width + spriteWidth
            || zombies[i].pos.y < (spriteHeight * -2)
            || zombies[i].pos.y > screen.height + spriteHeight)
        {
            var element = document.getElementById(zombies[i].id);
            element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
            zombies.splice(i, 1);
        }

    }

    for (var i = zombies.length - 1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
        //if the zombie has died, remove their corpse after some time
        if (zombies[i].state == stateDead) {
            zombies[i].corpseDelta += delta;

            if (zombies[i].corpseDelta > corpseDuration) {
                var element = document.getElementById(zombies[i].id);
                element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
                zombies.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
    }

}

var started = false;

var main = function () {
    var now = Date.now();
    var delta = now - then;
    if (started) {    
        cleanupZombies(delta / 1000);

        spawnZombies(delta / 1000);

        for (var i in zombies)
            zombies[i].Update(delta / 1000);
    }

    then = now;

    setTimeout(main, 30);
};

var then = Date.now();
setTimeout(main, 30);

setTimeout(function () {
    alert("Error 8102: Unexpected zombie attack. Please stand by...");
    started = true;
}, 2000)
```

Answer (score 3):

Redirect to `about:crash`, which shows the default crash screen on Chrome [won't work on modern versions of Chrome, Firefox, or other browsers]:

[image]

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=about:crash">
```

It probably doesn't qualify as a "full HTML page", but it will be rendered correctly by Chrome.
To try it, type this into the Chrome address bar:

```
data:text/html;base64,PG1ldGEgaHR0cC1lcXVpdj0icmVmcmVzaCIgY29udGVudD0iMDsgdXJsPWFib3V0OmNyYXNoIj4=
```

*I couldn't test this answer because I don't have a Chrome install handy, please remove this notice once you test it.*

Comment: I tried putting that text in the address bar of Chromium (mostly the same as Chrome), but it just resulted in a page with the contents `PG1ldGEgaHR0cC1lcXVpdj0icmVmcmVzaCIgY29udGVudD0iMDsgdXJsPWFib3V0OmNyYXNoIj4=`

Comment: @IanD.Scott Whoops! I accidentally typed `content` rather than `base64`. I edited my answer.

Comment: Your base64 just redirects me to `about:blank`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Glitchy scroll](http://c99.nl/f/44808.html)

No, that's not bad image compression. Unintended side effect from something else I was trying.

Try it out with the link in the title; The page starts looking weird while you scroll, and the scroll should become very jittery after a while. I think you need font smoothing of some sort activated, but everyone has this nowadays, right? The screenshot is from Chrome on OS X.

[image: Imgur]

#### The jQuery code:

```javascript
$( window ).scroll(function() {
    $('#main').clone().prependTo('body');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

## HTML + CSS + JavaScript/jQuery/jQuery UI

This simulates a Windows error dialog. (It drags, too!) Like all good error messages, it fulfills two main requirements:

1. It displays a cryptic error message meaning nothing to all but a few.
2. The buttons seem to do nothing when clicked except show the `wait` cursor.

See it in action at http://codepen.io/anon/pen/onbAi. (JSFiddle was not loading jQuery UI well.) It should display reasonably well on all browsers.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
<head><style>
body {
  font: 11px sans-serif;
}
#window {
  background-color: #ECE9D8;
  padding: 3px;
  width: 574px;
  margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
  -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
header {
  background-color: #1E74EF;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #003ac9 0%, #4492e5 100%);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #003ac9 0%, #4492e5 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #003ac9 0%, #4492e5 100%);
  clear: both;
  padding: 3px;
}
p {
  margin-left: 60px;
}
h1 {
  font: bold 13px sans-serif;
  color: white;
  margin: 1px;
}
button {
  background-color: #ECE9D8;
  outline: none;
  cursor: inherit;
}
#close {
  float: right;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0 2px;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  height: 18px;
  line-height: 16px;
}
#ok {
  width: 75px;
  height: 23px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 13px;
  display: block;
}
</style></head><body>
<div id="window">
  <header>
    <button id="close" title="Close">×</button>
    <h1><span id="browser"></span>Application Error</h1>
  </header>
  <p>The instruction at "</span>" referenced memory at "<span class="hex"></span>". The memory could not be "read".</p>
  <p>Click on OK to terminate the program</p>
  <button id="ok">OK</button>
</div>
<script src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>

$('#window').draggable({handle:'header'});

function randomHex(){
  return '0x'+(Math.floor(Math.random()*0xffffffff)).toString(16);
}

$('.hex').each(function(){
  $(this).text(randomHex());
});

var reg = /(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie)/i,
    browser = navigator.userAgent.match(reg)[0].toLowerCase();
if(!browser){
  browser = 'firefox';
} else if(browser == 'msie'){
  browser = 'ie';
}
$('#browser').text(browser + '.exe - ');

$('button').click(function(){
  $('html, body').css('cursor','wait');
});
</script>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tested this on my smartphone. I can't get it to load properly on c99.nl, though. Must be that obscure.

It makes your browser look possessed with some sort of obscure virus affecting the loading bar.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script>
window.location.href = document.location.href;
</script>
<title>Redirecting...</title>
<h3>Redirecting...</h3>
```

### Notes:

1. This can easily be tested locally by copying it into a plain text file, and the name or place doesn't matter beyond file extension. It is valid HTML5 + JavaScript (you can see for yourself [here](http://validator.w3.org/check)...only warning is missing `<meta charset=utf-8 />`).
2. Make sure that if you test it, especially on a mobile device, stop the loading loop first (same as cancelling a page load) before you exit, or it ***may crash***. (I learned this the hard way...)

> In case you hadn't noticed, it's continually redirecting to the same page. `window.location.href` and `document.location.href` are synonymous, so it's assigning the current location to its synonym. It could look like server lag or a browser hang, depending on the browser and largely it's caching mechanism.
>
> That last line is just for theme.

Comment: Actually, it is valid HTML5, barring the missing <title> tag (which is fixed).

Comment: @Sieg You can omit the `<html>`, `<head>`, `<body>`, and `<meta charset="utf-8" />` tags in HTML5. You can also omit 99% of the otherwise-important stuff in the `<!DOCTYPE>` tag, permitting the iconic `<!DOCTYPE html>` declaration for HTML5 instead of the lengthy `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">` for HTML 4.01 Strict.

Answer (score 0):

```
data:text/html, <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0"><script>document.write("Error Code : " + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000)  % 1000) + ". Description: Network connection error.")</script>
```

The error code keeps changing, and the computer goes noisy.

Answer (score 0):

Simulates an lagging loading spinner

http://c99.nl/f/104794.html

Sourcecode: http://jsfiddle.net/3QURA/2/

HTML:

```html
<div id="loader" style="">
<br/>
<div id="spinner">&nbsp;</div>
<br/>
<br/>
Loading...
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
body,html {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    color:white;
}
#spinner {
    background:transparent;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    left:calc(50% - 100px / 2);
    position:relative;
    -webkit-animation: load infinite 1s;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
    border-right:white 8px solid;
}
@-webkit-keyframes load {
    0% { -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg) }
    100% { -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg) }
}
.paused {
    -webkit-animation-play-state:paused;
}
#loader {
    font-family:Helvetica Light, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    left:0%;
    position:fixed;
    text-align:center;
    background:rgba(55,55,55,0.5);
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

JavaScript and jQuery:

```js
window.setInterval(update, 1000/2);
function update() {
window.setTimeout(function () {
    $("#spinner").addClass("paused");
},1000);
window.setTimeout(function () {
    $("#spinner").removeClass("paused");
},1200);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### [Chrome Crash Page](http://jsbin.com/serofe/1)

Actual Link: **chrome://crash/**

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
 <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAEIAAABCCAQAAABJXchjAAAAjklEQVR4Xu3ZgQbAIAAG4d7/pbeJxJCOWf26DozSh0RWrg0aAESIEEEtxJ6E6ICZUXrTc7MQZID5pyFEiPiwAMQPNYiIpyBEAwIoWBOEAACwJhHhmfCeEEH17++DEPwRlI/giRAhoow7ANE2gchkBN8c4GMQNI6JRHhjiqitAOyEWPsXqkq2QSxNhAgR4269KKbHaOQ5OgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Crash">
  <div>Aw, Shit!</div>
  <p>This page is really fucked up, run for the hills.</p>
  <button>Reload</button>
  <p>If it doesn't work, it's all your fault.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
html, button {
  user-select: none;
  cursor: wait;
  font-family: Calibri, Sans-serif;
  text-align: center; 
}
body {
  padding-top: 120px;
  background: #212e3d; 
  font-size: 80%;
  color: white;  
}
button {
  font-family: Calibri, Sans-serif;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
div {
  font-size: 140%;
}
```